# Can't call custom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am having trouble calling a custom plugin.. The plugin enlargeImage isn't being called at all from  the imageSwap jQuery code. I am new and still learning js. At this point, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help or guidance is appreciated :)

Plugin code

```
(function($){
    $.fn.enlargeImage = function() {
        return this.each(function() {

            alert("This is working!");
            // preload images
            $("#image_list a").(function() {
                var swappedImage = new Image();
                swappedImage.src = $(this).attr("href");
            });

                // set up event handlers for links    
            $("#image_list").find("a").click(function(evt) {
                // swap image
                var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
                $("#image").attr("src", imageURL);

                //swap caption
                var caption = $(this).attr("title");
                $("#caption").text(caption);

                // cancel the default action of the link
                evt.preventDefault();  // jQuery method that's cross-browser compatible
            }); // end click

            // move focus to first thumbnail
            $("li:first-child a:first-child").focus();
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

jqUERY CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#image_list').enlargeImage();
}); // end ready
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Image Swap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.imageSwap.js"></script>
    <script src="image_swap.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Ram Tap Combined Test</h1>
        <ul id="image_list">
            <li><a href="images/h1.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-1">
                <img src="thumbnails/t1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/h2.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-2">
                <img src="thumbnails/t2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/h3.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-3">
                <img src="thumbnails/t3.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/h4.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-4">
                <img src="thumbnails/t4.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/h5.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-5">
                <img src="thumbnails/t5.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/h6.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-6">
                <img src="thumbnails/t6.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>
        <h2 id="caption">James Allison: 1-1</h2>               
        <p><img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="image"></p>
    </section>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace this code

```
$("#image_list a").(function() {
    var swappedImage = new Image();
    swappedImage.src = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

to

```
$("#image_list a").each(function() {
    var swappedImage = new Image();
    swappedImage.src = $(this).attr("href");
});
```